# how to generate tinymce to ajax generated textarea

Tags: javascript

how to generate tinymce to ajax generated textarea
Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to do with AJAX?  Are you trying to submit the textarea with actually posting the form?

Answer (score 1):

If you show me your code, I may be able to help you better. However, You should be able to call this function and pass it the id of the Ajax generated TextArea.

```
//add this to your Ajax callback that generates the TextArea
//replace with the Id of the new textarea
var myTextArea = document.getElementById("MyNewTextArea"); 
generateTinyMCE(myTextArea);

//Add this function to your script tag
function generateTinyMCE(id) {
 if (!tinyMCE.get(id))
   tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
 else
   tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
}
```